# Cocoa runModal stuck

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-mountain-lion

I have a problem with runModal function. It stucks.
I just get a blank white rectangle on the screen and that's it.

I would love to paste a code here but it is extremely complicating system, where view creation is in one file, and runModal is in another. I also have more than 50 threads running when it happens.

I just wondered, maybe someone can give me a lead of what to look for? What call in other thread can block runModal function?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using runModal from main thread ?

Comment: No. It is used from another thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this not sure if it helps:-

```
if ([NSApp modalWindow] == self.window)
        [NSApp stopModal];
```

Comment: Where exactly, BEFORE runModal (What is the point) or AFTER runModal (Which is impossible since runModal is stucked)?

Comment: Yes that is true, but for what scenarios you are using run modal. Can you paste you code little bit related to run modal so that if any alternative was there then we can replace the same